# Bare bones level system receiving errors

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm having issues with a very bare bones level system with my discord bot, here's the error and code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands,tasks

@client.event
async def on_message(message, member):
    if message.author.bot == False:
        if xp >= 250:
            level =+ 1
            await ctx.send(f'{member.mention} Has leveled up')
            if level >= 12:
                await member.add_roles(discord.Object(id='800794726935822358'))
            elif level >= 22:
                await member.add_roles(discord.Object(id='800794900370292746'))
        else:
            xp =+ 1
```

The error:

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Jeremy\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'
```

Comment: You've defined `on_message` to take two parameters (`message` and `member`), but from what I can see of the [discord api](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_message), `on_message` is only expected to receive a single parameter (`message`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @larsks said in the comment. Only pass `message` as a parameter for `on_message`. To get the member, instead do:

`member = message.author`
This sets the `member` variable to the author of the message.

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    member = message.author

    if message.author.bot == False:
        if xp >= 250:
            level =+ 1
            await message.reply(f'{member.mention} Has leveled up')
            if level >= 12:
                await member.add_roles(discord.Object(id='800794726935822358'))
            elif level >= 22:
                await member.add_roles(discord.Object(id='800794900370292746'))
        else:
            xp =+ 1
```